# Problems ranking in different countries for .com TLD

Tags: search-engine-indexing, search-engines, ranking, local-seo, country-specific

Certain page on my site shows up on the first page of 'google.com' but when I'm searching for the same phrase in google by changing the country in the Google's search settings, it doesn't show up on the 1st page.

Say for instance, if I search for this phrase: hire a zoho developer
It appears on the Google's first page.

But the same page is not showing up on the first page of the Google search results for the same phrase when I'm changing the country in the Google Search settings.

My competitors' sites rank consistently across all geographical versions of Google. Is there something I am missing out on?

Answer (score 2):

Generally google tries to show geo-specific or location specific results.

Google has several ways of determining target locale, for example:

- A target locale specified using Search Console's International
  Targeting report.
- Country-code top-level domain names (ccTLDs). These are tied to a
  specific country (for example .de for Germany, .cn for China), and
  therefore are a strong signal to both users and search engines that
  your site is explicitly intended for a certain country.
- hreflang statements, whether in tags, headers, or sitemaps.
- Server location (through the IP address of the server). The server
  location is often physically near your users and can be a signal
  about your site’s intended audience. Most websites use CDNs or are
  hosted in a country with better webserver infrastructure, so it is
  not a definitive signal.
- Other sources of clues as to the intended audience of your site which
  can include local addresses and phone numbers on the pages, the use
  of local language and currency, links from other local sites, etc.

So if you are giving google signals that your site should be targeted only to specific regions like USA, that may explain it. If you want your site to be considered "international" then look at ways you can remove region targeting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting up website across multiple countries. For google rating, it is important to let google understand your multiple-country setting, especially which page are targeted at which regions and languages. It can help google rank only relevant pages in search research for the particular visitor based on his location, avoid SEO penalty of duplicate content due to multiple versions with only slight variant for your multiple-country setting.

One thing is to set hreflang tags demonstrating multi-regional website structure. A example is as below:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/gb/" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/au/" hreflang="en-au" />
```

Here is one more point. Google just released an import update regrading google ranking factors. It newly adds "page user experience", more specifically, how fast your webpage loads matters. I suggest you to check your webpage loading time among multiple-country setting, for example, the speed of running geo redirect javascript.